# How to correctly document R6 self

Tags: r, roxygen2, r6

I have a function built with an R6class and was wondering the best way to pass `devtools::check()` is. Currently this repex gives the note

```
> checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  obj_gen : <anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘self’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    self
```

It only gives the note, however, when `self` is actually called. Ie in the print function, but not in the assignment inside initialise.

In the Tidyverse ([here](https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dbplyr/src/R/progress.R)), `importFrom R6 R6Class` is used. In this case however the calling of `self` in the print function seems to trigger the global variables note.

#### Repex

```
#' func
#' @param ... opts
#' @examples
#'\dontrun{
#' obj_gen(bar = "fubar")
#'}
obj_gen <- function(...){

  #' @importFrom R6 R6Class
  obj <- R6::R6Class("my_class",
              public = list(
                foo = NULL,
                initialize = function(bar = NA){
                  self$foo <- bar
                },
                print = function(){
                  cat("Anyone for ",
                      self$foo,
                      "?",
                      sep = "")
                }
              )
  )
  obj$new(...)
}
```

A collegue very helpfully suggested adding it to `globalVariables`([info](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/08/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable/)) which I am considering. Id like to know if there is a better way to deal with it, using documentation, however :)

My Roxygen version is 7.1.1.

Comment: I will be glad if you accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry for delay - have some info to add to this (answer) which will help users in future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with a dummy `self <- NA` definition.

```r
#' func
#' @param ... opts
#' @import R6
#' @examples
#'\dontrun{
#' obj_gen(bar = "fubar")
#'}
obj_gen <- function(...){
  self <- NA
  obj <- R6Class("my_class",
                     public = list(
                       foo = NULL,
                       initialize = function(bar = NA) {
                         self$foo <- bar
                       },
                       print = function() {
                         cat("Anyone for ",
                             self$foo,
                             "?",
                             sep = "")
                       }
                     )
  )
  obj$new(...)
}
```